# Configuring tightvnc to launch a program on startup

Tags: ubuntu, remote-desktop, tightvnc

I'm following this how-to ( http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=541656&highlight=ssh+vncviewer ) and managed to connect to the desktop.

Unfortunately, all I see is the Ubuntu background. I tried editing the startup script according to the description in the how-to, but I'm not proficient enough in bash-scripting to make it work.

How do I start a program that lives in my home folder?

Specifically, I'm trying to display UbiGraph over the vnc connection.

Comment: I oversaw the part where I have to restart the server to take effect, but the question still stands: how do I open a program living in my home directory?